# After choose time I get undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

After I choose a time and submit a form, I get **undefine** 
When I open console, there aren't any error.

```
 $('.timepicker').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
            interval: 30,
            minTime: '10',
            maxTime: '3:00pm',
            startTime: '10:00',
            dynamic: true,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                minDate: +1, maxDate: "+3M"
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var appointmentTime = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
            var splitData = "";
            if (appointmentTime.indexOf("") > 0) {
                splitData = appointmentTime.split(" ");
            }
            else {
                splitData = appointmentTime.split("T");
            }
            var time = splitData[1].substring(0, 5);
            if (time.slice(-1) == ":") {
                time = time.substring(0, time.length - 1);
            }
            var amPmTime = splitData[2];
            $('#datepicker').attr('value', splitData[0]);
            $('#timepicker').attr('value', time + ' ' + amPmTime);
        });
```

And in my field I get something like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npNrv.png)

Any idea what could be problem ?

Comment: I guess amPmTime is undefined because splitData only has 2 elements because there is only one T in appointmentTime.

Comment: @James Thank you for answer, but what is the best way to resolve this ? 
var amPmTime = splitData[2];

Comment: You will have to find another way to get the am/pm out of the string.  splitData[1] is the *time* part of the string, and that's where I suspect you will find your am/pm, but you will have to extract it.

Comment: Thank you @James :)